# Get Index in jQuery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am using the jQuery template plugin and don't know how to get the index of items:
http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Here is my code:

```
<script id="optionTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    {{each Answers}}
        <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="group1" value="${this.AnswerID}" /></th>
            <td>${this.AnswerText}</td><!-- add number in this line--->
        </tr>
    {{/each}}  
    </table>
</script>
```

I want to show the answer in the format like the following

1)answer1, 2)answer2, 3)answer3

or

a)answer1, b)answer2, c)answer3

What should I do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's an implicit `$index` (and `$value`) available inside the [`{{each}}` loop](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/), you can use that here:

```
<script id="optionTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    {{each Answers}}
        <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="group1" value="${this.AnswerID}" /></th>
            <td>${this.AnswerText} ${$index + 1}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}  
    </table>
</script>
```

You'll probably want to add `1` because it's `0`-based, like I have above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you to get the index in jQuery template:-

```js
$("#optionTmpl").tmpl(data, {
  dataArrayIndex: function (item) {
    return $.inArray(item, data);
  }
}).appendTo("#TableBody");
```

You can use this `${$item.dataArrayIndex($item.data)}` to get the current index

```html
<script id="optionTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <th><input type="radio" name="group1" value="${AnswerID}" /></th>
      <td>${AnswerText} ${$item.dataArrayIndex($item.data)}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</script>
```