# Get index within jquery tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

No, this is not a repeat of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213033/get-index-in-jquery-template)... a little related though, so i will use the code from that Q for comparison.

I am attempting to get the index from within a nested template, using the [{{tmpl}} tag](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/). Using the tmlp tag is much like an {{each}} tag as in the question linked above, however the $index property is not present.

```
<script id="answerTable" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     {{tmpl(answersObj) '#answers' }}
    </table>
</script>

<script id="answers" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="radio" name="group1" value="---!INDEX HERE!---" /></th>
        <td>${AnswerText}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

I dont want to wind up with a messy way to do this- i would prefer to modify the lib if possible. Anyone have any ideas where the current lib could be modified to support this feature - [git hub source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/raw/master/jquery.tmpl.js). This code is a little over my head, im short on time, and understanding this lib is not within my current projects scope ;)

Comment: little strange wanting temporary rep

Comment: ha. well you cant add bounty unless you have at least 75... anyways i answered the Q myself. so no need for the up-vote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK had to modify the template lib. 
see [this link](https://github.com/clarkbox/jquery-tmpl/commit/993e6fa128c5991723316032abe12ff0cbbb9805) for github patch.

line 150-155 of original (current version) of jquery.tmpl.js

```
ret = jQuery.isArray( data ) ?
        jQuery.map( data, function( dataItem ) {
        return dataItem ? newTmplItem( options, parentItem, tmpl, dataItem ) : null;
        }) :
        [ newTmplItem( options, parentItem, tmpl, data ) ];
return topLevel ? jQuery( build( parentItem, null, ret ) ) : ret;
```

modified to support $index

```
ret = jQuery.isArray( data ) ?
        jQuery.map( data, function( dataItem, index ) {
        if(dataItem){dataItem.$index = index;}
        return dataItem ? newTmplItem( options, parentItem, tmpl, dataItem ) : null;
        }) :
        [ newTmplItem( options, parentItem, tmpl, data ) ];
return topLevel ? jQuery( build( parentItem, null, ret ) ) : ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also learned of another technique that may or may not work for your scenario...

you can use **jQuery.inArray** to get the index from the parent data object - assuming youre keeping your parent data object in sync.